# GetMessage() ,for reading message from message queue

Tags: win32-process

I am using PostThreadMessage() & GetMessage() for sending data to the queue and reading data from the queue.But i want to check whether that data is in queue or not.can u tell how it will possible to check that which i was sending by PostThreadMessage().

Answer (score 2):

Look at [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943(VS.85).aspx) with flag PM_NOREMOVE

Comment: is there any sample are there?can u send me pls